# why addEventListener fire the event

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, removeeventlistener

addNode_button click event handler is waiting for input to do something.
But I want to stop event listener by pressing esc.
I made simplified example which show that addEventListener in keydown fire 'click' on button.
I can't understand why.

```js
addNode_but.addEventListener('click',addNodeButClick);
function addNodeButClick(){
        let value = nodePt_inp.value;out1.value = new Date();
        let waitingValue = 'try to stop clock by escape,then input something to stop';
        function callMeAgain(){addNode_but.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'))};
        switch (value){
            case '': nodePt_inp.value = waitingValue;
            case waitingValue: setTimeout(callMeAgain,100);break;
            default:    out1.value = "only now I've stopped";
        }
}
document.addEventListener('keydown',escape);
function escape(evt){
    if (evt.key==='Escape'){
        addNode_but.removeEventListener('click',addNodeButClick);
        nodePt_inp.value = "";               
        addNode_but.addEventListener('click',addNodeButClick);
        }
}
```

```html
<input style='display:block;width:60ch' type="text" id="nodePt_inp" name='pt'>
<button id='addNode_but' class='button'>clickMe and try to stop by esc</button>
<output id='out1'>output</output>
```

Comment: Your question is entirely unclear. Your code does exactly what you've programmed it to do! If you explain what it is you're trying to achieve (Rather than how you think you have achieved it) we might be able to help

Comment: I'm trying to stop eventListener (which is in loop) by pressing esc

Comment: @muratgu break must be missed,it is ok for this code

Comment: The logic is wrong. It won't stop until you enter something. Otherwise it's just calling itself every 100ms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to stop a `setTimeout` call you should keep reference to the result of that call and call `clearTimeout`

```js
addNode_but.addEventListener('click',addNodeButClick);
var timerId = null;
function addNodeButClick(){
        let value = nodePt_inp.value;out1.value = new Date();
        let waitingValue = 'try to stop clock by escape,then input something to stop';
        function callMeAgain(){addNode_but.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'))};
        nodePt_inp.value = waitingValue;
        timerId = setTimeout(callMeAgain,100);
}
document.addEventListener('keydown',escape);
function escape(evt){
    if (evt.key==='Escape'){
        clearTimeout(timerId);
    }
}
```

```html
<input style='display:block;width:60ch' type="text" id="nodePt_inp" name='pt'>
<button id='addNode_but' class='button'>clickMe and try to stop by esc</button>
<output id='out1'>output</output>
```

Comment: many thanks, I didn't think that setTimeout "hangs" eventListener

Comment: where have you got this information about setTimeout and removing event listener?:)

Comment: @IgorFomenko I don't understand either of those questions - nothing hangs and setTimeout does not have an event listener! But glad this helped you.